# Converting html location to docx with ReactJS

Tags: c#, html, reactjs, docx, html-to-docx

I'm designing an editable place on the website and those textboxes are for the next user to fill in information.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaJSq.png)

Currently I am using coordinates to save the position of the textbox. This makes it difficult for me to convert from html to docx.

```
<div className='parent' style={{ border: "1px solid black", height: "100vh", width: "100%", display: "inline-block" }}>
                            <div>
                                {inputArrs.map((item) => {
                                    return <Draggable className='draggable' id={item.id} onStop={handleStop} onMouseDown={handleMouseMove}
                                        defaultPosition={positions === null ? { x: 0, y: 0 } : !positions[item.id] ?
                                            { x: 0, y: 0 } : { x: positions[item.id].x, y: positions[item.id].y }}><input id={item.id} key={item.id}
                                                type="text" onChange={event => handleChange(event, item.id)} value={item.value}></input></Draggable>;
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```